# Stop content from loading through server

Tags: php, jquery, apache, .htaccess

I was wondering if it is possible to block certain things from running through server.

Example.  I am apart of ad network and some of the ad's are sexually suggestive.  I have asked to not get these ad's on my page but was told they can't control the delivery network to block only adult ad's.

Is it possible in apache or htaccess or something to program the url's of the "dirty" ad's and have them not show up to the end user??

Sorry if my question is worded poorly. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to find a different ad provider.

Comment: nah... who cares. That's why we have ad-blockers. Anyway, I don't think your ad provider will be quite happy with what you're trying to do, I'd first set about reading the terms and agreements... you know, that big blob of text that nobody ever reads, but mindlessly agrees to?

Comment: No, you can't do it serverside, and you most likely also can't do it client side.

Answer (score 0):

The below code in htaccess denies access to sexualwebsite.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*sexualwebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Replace sexualwebsite with whichever domain you want to block. Source: http://davidwalsh.name/block-domain

Comment: This only blocks people who are linking *to* the site (e.g. hotlinking an image), not an ad being served on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ads are not actually served by your server but injected into the page on the client using Javascript. Nothing you modify on your server would affect which ads are being pulled in by that client-side script.

It's might technically be possible to have some additional Javascript to monitor the ad-serving script and disallow the loading of an ad, but it would be a hack and would break if your ad provider changes something. It would also probably violate your ad provider's terms of service resulting in you not getting paid.

The only reliable way to control which ads are being served is by some API or control panel that would have to be provided by your ad network. If they don't offer this functionality, then there's probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks friends.  I didn't think this was possible because of cross-site issues but I thought I would ask anyways in case you guys had a good solution.

Regarding an API.  Couldn't one be built?  But if the ad server changes things, the API would have to be edited each time correct?

Comment: It all depends on the ad service. I'm mainly familiar with Google's, and you can choose what ads you want displayed by logging into your profile. The Javascript you add to your site just contains a unique ID that is tied to your account and used to get ads from their servers. The API needs to be provided by their service...